# Performance in sql

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

So i got one select from view and two tables, long story short,

**first execution is ok, less than 1s, after first execution i lost performance, execution last about 30s**

trick - after i change string add '(space)' or take off(somewhere in select) performance first execution is again 1s and second or more is 30s

exec plan i guess is the same first and second+ time execution...

Question - whats happening?

cache?

Yes, tried to rewrite in 5 another ways same, 30 seconds if more then one execution,if not changing select adding ' ' or take it off.

hope someone can help me :)

Best regards

Comment: Someone stolen my crystal ball, and you are too far for my mind-reading to work... without clear information about the query, the table, the indexes and all the technical stuff no-one can answer this

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, what you've done, and how rigorously you've checked that there is in fact a problem to begin with. Maybe the system is just busy right now, someone submitted a heavy query and tied up a lot of resources. Maybe not. But either way, there's no way at all for anyone to answer this question as it currently stands

Comment: Thanks for your time, like i said, exec plan is ok, in test environment its all ok, less then 1s always,  besides plan is 206 steps.. i dont think its good idea to paste it here, problem remains.. its not about index, its about something more... hoped someone had the same problem and could answer on hit, will try Jonearles suggestion about cardinality feedback... but still... anyway thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem caused by [cardinality feedback](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/cardinality_feedback).  Cardinality feedback compares the estimated
 number of rows from an execution plan with the actual number of rows.  If the difference is large the *second* execution will use the more accurate numbers.  The optimizer
 generally works better when it has more accurate statistics.  As with any complex model, there are weird cases where more accurate input causes problems.

To determine if this is really the case, find the SQL_ID with a statement like this:

```
select sql_id from v$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like '%some unique string%';
```

Then find the current execution plan for that statement:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => '<sql_id from above>'));
```

If cardinality feedback was used there will be something like this in the Note section:

```
Note
-----
   - cardinality feedback used for this statement
```

There are many ways that execution plans can change over time.  To know for sure, please add the explain plan to the original question.  Also the exact version of Oracle is important, there have been been significant changes to the new automatic re-optimization features in 12c.

Comment: Thanks, Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production,  Ok, will try to find whats about  cardinality feedback.